# How to .count() subobjects of list.stream()?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, mapping, java-stream

```
public static int amountKurse (List<Studie> lstd) {
    int result = (int) lstd.stream().map(Studie::getKurse).count();
    return result;
}

private Map<Kurs,Integer> kurse = new HashMap<>();

public Set<Kurs> getKurse(){
    return kurse.keySet();
}
```

I want to count the number of `Kurse` in all my `Studie` objects.
My current result is `20`, when it should be `132`
I am guessing that my function is only counting the amount of `Studie`
Would be grateful for some help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `getKurse()` returns a `Set` and you want to count the total number of elements of all these `Set`s, use:

```
int result = (int) lstd.stream().flatMap(s -> s.getKurse().stream()).count();
```

or, if you want to avoid counting duplicates:

```
int result = (int) lstd.stream().flatMap(s -> s.getKurse().stream()).distinct().count();
```

Comment: @Finnn No, `flatMap` transforms the `Stream<Studie>` to a `Stream<Kurs>` (your original `map` attempt transformed the `Stream` to a `Stream<Set<Kurs>>`).

Comment: Is it possible to output both count and print each object ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `flatMap` in order to [*flatten*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap) your stream of `Studie` to stream of `Kurse`. Then simply `.count()` the items in the stream:

```
int count = (int) lstd.stream()                // Stream<Studie>
                      .map(Studie::getKurse)   // Stream<Set<Kurse>>
                      .flatMap(Set::stream)    // Stream<Kurse>
                      .count();
```